# eclipse: how to deactivate auto-adjusting of method brackets

Tags: eclipse

I have turned off all of the intelligent typing preferences that I can find ...

however, when I create a method, eclipse forces my { to align left ...

```
private my_method()
{
}
```

I prefer:

```
private my_meth()
  {
  }
```

it also auto left-aligns nested brackets:

```
private my_meth()
{
  if ( true )
{
}
}
```

where I prefer:

```
private my_meth()
  {
    if ( true )
      {
      }
  }
```

is there a way to tell eclipse to stop doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> Braces.`
The brace position you want is `Next line indented`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GO TO

> Preferences  ->  Java  ->  Code Style  ->
>   Formatter -> Edit -> Braces

set your preferred margine then select your code and press

> Ctrl + Shift + F